# Entity Framework does not display the last change from the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework does not display the last changes from the database, but after sometime it shows the updated contents. I don't any special cache on the server or on the page.
Thank in advance.
Jack
Here is the code i use to get the list, that has problem:

```
var m =
    from relation in ett.Article_Relations
    from article in ett.Article_Articles
    from content in ett.Article_Contents
    where relation.MenuItemID == id
    where relation.Article_Articles.ArticleID == article.ArticleID 
    where content.LanguageID == LanguageID 
    where article.ArticleID == content.Article_Articles.ArticleID
    select new ArticleViewModel
    {
        ArticleID = article.ArticleID,
        IsActive = article.IsActive,
        Author = article.ArticleAuthor,
        Content =  content,
        DateCreated = article.DateCreated
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the query you show, therefore I expect you are using the `ObjectContext` for a longer period than intended. Are you caching an object context in the ASP.NET cache or Session? If so, you should create an `ObjectContext` at least once per request. Never less.

The thing is that the Entity Framework `ObjectContext` is a [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). It caches objects during its lifetime. This means that when you query the database for an object that is already in cache, EF will retrieve that value from the database (most of the time), but will throw away the results, and return the cached object. This could explain why you are not seeing updates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives me some idea where the problem could be. Right now I actually avoid (but not solved) this problem by writing the code direct in the controller(my project is in MVC) instead of calling form a public class.